# How to invoke a function from another node script?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to invoke a function from one node into another

Node1_script:

```
extends Position2D

func sample():
    print('well you invoked me, now what?')
```

Node2_script:

```
tool
...


func some_function():
    print($"Node1".sample());
```

but it gives the error:

> Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'sample'

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. I would look into whether or not the node reference is correct.

Comment: By the way, the node reference implies that `Node1` is a child of the other node (the one with the script that references it).

Comment: @Theraot my apologies I forgot to add that the script was in tool mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I got the problem, it was in `tool` mode

for future reference, if you want to invoke a function in tool mode you have to make sure the function definition is also in tool mode:

Node1_script:

```
extends Position2D
tool

func sample():
    print('well you invoked me, now what?')
```

Node2_script:

```
tool
...


func some_function():
    print($"Node1".sample());
```